# laravel authentication with eloquent driver on roles

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to authenticate users in my Laravel application.

I am encountering the following problem:

- using driver **database** in auth.php: I can login using auth::attempt(), and auth::check is working, but I can't validate if the logged in user has a certain role.
- using driver **eloquent** in auth.php: I can login using auth::attempt(), but auth::check is not working. I can however check the role of the logged in user.

edit (question): How can I fix this so that with only one of the drivers, i can do a complete authentication and role check?

Migration tables:

```
Schema::create('users', function ($table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('group_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('name', 64);
        $table->string('email', 64)->unique();
        $table->string('username', 64)->unique();
        $table->string('phone', 13);
        $table->string('address', 64);
        $table->boolean('isresponsible');
        $table->string('password', 64);
        $table->rememberToken()->nullable();
    });
Schema::create('roles', function ($table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
    });

Schema::create('users_roles', function ($table) {
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
        }
    );
Schema::table('users_roles', function($table){
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
    });
```

model class User

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;`
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;`
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {


use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'users';
public $timestamps = false;

public static $rules = ['name' => 'required', 'group_id' => 'required', 'email' => 'required', 'phone' => 'required'];
protected $fillable = ['name', 'group_id', 'email', 'phone', 'address', 'isresponsible', 'password'];

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

public function group()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Group');
}

public function userroles(){
    return $this->hasMany('Userrole');
}

public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Role', 'users_roles');
}

public function hasRole($check)
{
    dd($this->roles->toArray());
    return in_array($check, array_fetch($this->roles->toArray(), 'name'));
}

public function setBasicPassword($id){
    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->password = Hash::make('changeme');
    $user->save();
}

public function isValid()
{
    $validation = Validator::make($this->attributes, static::$rules);
    if ($validation->passes()) return true;
    $this->messages = $validation->messages();
    return false;
}


/**
 * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getReminderEmail()
{
    // TODO: Implement getReminderEmail() method.
}

/**
 * Get the unique identifier for the user.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getAuthIdentifier()
{
    return $this->email;
}

/**
 * Get the password for the user.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

/**
 * Get the token value for the "remember me" session.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRememberToken()
{
    return $this->remember_token;
}

public function setRememberToken($value)
{
    $this->remember_token = $value;
}

public function getRememberTokenName()
{
    return 'remember_token';
}
}
```

model Class Role

```
class Role extends Eloquent
{

protected $table = 'roles';
public $timestamps = false;

public static $rules = ['role_id' => 'required', 'name' => 'required'];
protected $fillable = ['name'];

/**
 * Get users with a certain role
 */
public function userroles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'users_roles');
}
}
```

HomeController authentication function

```
 public function authenticate(){
    $rules = array(
        'email'    => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|alphaNum|min:3'
    );
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('login')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
    } else {
        $userdata = array(
            'email' => Input::get('email'),
            'password' => Input::get('password')
        );
        if (Auth::attempt($userdata, true)) {
            return Redirect::action('HomeController@index');

        } else {
            return Redirect::action('HomeController@login')->withInput();
        }
    }
}
```

USING THE DATABASE DRIVER
- auth:attempt() and auth::check are working

```
$this->beforeFilter('admin', ['only' => ['index']]); //filter in controller
//filter in filters;php
Route::filter('admin', function()
{
if(!Auth::check()) return Redirect::action('HomeController@index');
if(!Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')) return View::make('errors.401');
});
```

This fails with 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser::hasRole()'

**EDIT** The **database** driver return a GenericUser Object, and I need my own User object. Don't know where I can change this.

Workaround:I'd rather not use this, ugly code and filters (or views) should not need to do this

```
Route::filter('admin', function()
{
    if(!Auth::check()) return Redirect::action('HomeController@index');
    $user = User::find((Auth::user()->id));
    if(!$user->hasRole('admin')){ return View::make('errors.401');}
});
```

USING THE ELOQUENT DRIVER

- auth::attempt() succeeds
- auth::check() fails
- no error on the filter

Comment: Have you tried only `Auth::attempt($userdata)` without the remember option?

Comment: yes, it gives the same result

Comment: Does `Auth::id()` work? (when using Eloquent)

Comment: that returns the username/email address

Comment: Ahaaaa!! writing an answer now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your implementation of `getAuthIdentifier()`. This method should actually return the primary key of your table and not the username that's used for logging in.

So yours should look like this:

```
public function getAuthIdentifier(){
    return $this->id;
}
```

Or actually, I recommend you clean up your model a bit more since all of the `getSomeAuthStuff` methods are implemented in the two traits.

Use the [default model on github](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/models/User.php) as a base and add all your custom code (roles methods, rules etc)

#### Background info

The value returned from `getAuthIdentifier()` will be stored in the session.
When using `check()` afterwards, `retrieveById` will be called on the `UserProvider`. And the `EloquentUserProvider` does this:

```
public function retrieveById($identifier)
{
    return $this->createModel()->newQuery()->find($identifier);
}
```

It uses `find()` which searches for the model by it's primary key (usually `id`)