# GenericUser Laravel

Tags: authentication, laravel, laravel-4, model

Is there a way to overwrite the GenericUser class in Laravel?

Current authentication uses GenericUser as a return object for Auth:: operartions,

I want it to be my User class from my model. Is this feasible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source you're looking at is `DatabaseUserProvider`. This provider works without models and will be used if your auth driver (in `app/config/auth.php`) is set to `database`.

What you're actually using is the `EloquentUserProvider` which uses the model class defined in the config. The default is `'model' => 'User'` which is the User model Laravel ships with.

You can change that value to any class name. But make sure to implement the necessary interfaces and add  the traits. You basically need pretty much everything the [default `User` model](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/models/User.php) has.

Comment: So I cant change the GenericUser class? This post was a subproblem from [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27795057/laravel-authentication-with-eloquent-driver-on-roles, if you can, please take a look at it.

Comment: Are you using the `database` driver?

Comment: yes, for the moment i am, the problem when i am using the eloquent driver is that authentication is not stored

Comment: Ok in this case, no you can't change `GenericUser`. You need to figure it out with the `eloquent` driver. I'll take a look at your other question and see if I find something...

Answer (score 1):

Laravel already uses the default `User` model supplied as the authentication model.

You can customise this further in `config\auth.php`. The default is to use `'model' => 'User',` - but you can change it to be something else.